# Excel VBA to find dd & dt tag

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch data from site souq .com

```
http://saudi.souq.com/sa-en/oneplus-3-dual-sim-64gb-4g-lte-graphite-10880010/i/
```

source is like this,

```
<div id="specs-full"><dt>Brand</dt><dd>OnePlus</dd>
```

and i am using this code

```
spec1 = Trim(Doc.getElementById("specs-full").getElementsByTagName("dt")(0).innerText)

spec2 = Trim(Doc.getElementById("specs-full").getElementsByTagName("dd")(0).innerText)
```

problem is that there are many dd & dt tag, and i dont know how many as i am fetching data for many url's

so i need code that find number of dd & dt tag in "specs-full" tag

Comment: Use a HTMLElementCollection and set it to getElementById("specs-full").getElementsByTagName("dt")   These links should help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx  and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14161/Automation-of-Internet-Explorer-Using-shdocvw-dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about solution like this

```
  Set All_dd = Doc.getElementById("specs-full").getElementsByTagName("dd")

  Counter=1
  For Each dd In All_dd 
       Counter=Counter+1
  Next 

  msgbox Counter
```

And this blog explains various techniques you can use for VBA webscraping.
http://www.excelvbasolutions.com/2016/02/web-scraping-collecting-data-from.html

Comment: thanks this worked well, i need one more thing... how can i get that all data from dd tag in one cell instead of many cells

Comment: right now i added loop with "counter" tag that add data from dd tag in many cells, but i need all data from dd tag in one cell...
got it?, or i need to explain more about what i need?

Comment: Could you please post your coding part