# How to get data from website's dd tag via VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from a website, but I cannot get this part of my VBA code to work.
I have tried to look here, e.g. [Excel VBA to find dd & dt tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037091/excel-vba-to-find-dd-dt-tag) but I could not find the answer.

This is the HTML code I am trying to get data from:

```
<div @*id="show7" class="collapse visible" *@>
<h3 class="rapport__h3">Folkbokföring</h3>
<dl class="rapport__list m-b-25">
    <dt>Gatuadress</dt>
    <dd/>
    <dt>Postnummer</dt>
    <dd/>
    <dt>Postort</dt>
    <dd/>
    <dt>Kommun</dt>
    <dd>
    </dd>
    <dt>Län</dt>
    <dd>&#xD6;rebro (18)</dd>
</dl>
<h3 class="rapport__h3">Särskild adress</h3>
<dl class="rapport__list m-b-25">
    <dt>Gatuadress</dt>
    <dd class="UpplysningTableSecondTd">Poste Restante</dd>
    <dt>Postadress</dt>
    <dd class="UpplysningTableSecondTd">701 00 &#xD6;rebro</dd>
</dl>
```

I am trying to retrieve the `class="UpplysningTableSecondTd"` data.
Neither of the below is working, and I have tried different things.

```
Set All_dd = oHDoc.getElementsByClassName("rapport__list m-b-25").getElementsByClassName("UpplysningTableSecondTd")(0).innerText
Set All_dd = oHDoc.getElementsById("show7").getElementsByTag("UpplysningTableSecondTd")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.

```
Debug.Print oHDoc.getElementsByClassName("UpplysningTableSecondTd").Item(0).innerText
Debug.Print oHDoc.getElementsByClassName("UpplysningTableSecondTd").Item(1).innerText
```